# Is there a way to bulk delete a list of customers using the Stripe API?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

Following a company spinoff, we need to delete a list of ~1200 old customers from our stripe account. I'm currently trying to do it using python via their API. The code to delete a customer via the API looks like this:

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = "test-api-key"

cu = stripe.Customer.retrieve("customer_id")
cu.delete()
```

I have a csv of all 1200 customers I'd like to delete from my stripe account, but the API won't read them as a list if I paste them into the `customer_id` field. Is there a way to run this bulk delete, or do I have to remove all of my customers one by one?

Answer (score 2):

You could just perform this with a list comprehension:

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = "test-api-key"

list_of_customers = ['customer_1','customer_2','customer_3']
[stripe.Customer.retrieve(i).delete() for i in list_of_customers]
```